# Remove previous WIDGETS on selecting options from Menubar in TKINTER

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I have a menu bar which has 2 options

***[1]TO ADD DATA***

***[2]TO UPDATE THE DATA***

When I select an option the widgets load in the window. When I select the other option after that , the previous widgets stay & new widgets overlapped. How do I keep the window & destroy the existing widgets over it.
I have not attached the original code with other menu options due to its size, however the code snippet replicates the actual scenario.

I have tried **destroy()** **exit()** & calling the *function* again

```
from tkinter import *
root = None
data = None
def _add(dt):
      global data
      data = dt
      print(data, 'ADDED')

def _edit(new_dt):
      global data
      data = new_dt
      print('UPDATED')
      print("DATA =", data)

def cust_add():
      global root
      global data
      lbl = Label(root,text="ADD NAME:")
      ent = Entry(root)
      btn = Button(root, text='ADD', command=lambda: _add(ent.get()))
      lbl.pack()
      ent.pack()
      btn.pack()

def cust_edit():
      global root
      global data
      lbl = Label(root, text="UPDATE NAME:")
      ent = Entry(root)
      btn = Button(root, text="UPDATE", command=lambda: _edit(ent.get()))
      lbl.pack()
      ent.pack()
      btn.pack()


def homepage():
      global root
      root = Tk()
      root.geometry('300x400')
      root.title('CAR  FLEET  MANAGEMENT  SYSTEM')
      back_image = PhotoImage(file='icons/background3.png')
      back_label = Label(root, image=back_image)
      back_label.place(x=0, y=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)
      menus = Menu()
      cst = Menu(menus, tearoff=FALSE)
      cst.add_command(label="Add New Customer", command=cust_add)
      cst.add_command(label="Change Customer Details", command=cust_edit)
      menus.add_cascade(label='CUSTOMERS', menu=cst)
      root.config(menu=menus)
      root.mainloop()
homepage()
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand what you want correctly.  It's probably better to create two frames for Add Customer and Update Customer.  Then show and hide them as required.  Like this the widgets are created once and reused as required.  I've tried to change your code as little as possible.

I've used grid and grid_remove to hide and show.  I couldn't find a pack_remove.
**Edit:** Below changed to use pack_forget() which in this simple case seems to work OK.

```
import tkinter as tk

root = None
data = None
def _add(dt):
    global data
    data = dt
    print(data, 'ADDED')

def _edit(new_dt):
    global data
    data = new_dt
    print('UPDATED')
    print("DATA =", data)

def homepage():
    global root

    def cust_edit():
        # c_add.grid_remove()    Old grid version replaced by pack version
        # c_upd.grid()            
        c_add.pack_forget()       # Hide Add Customer
        c_upd.pack()              # Show Update Customer

    def cust_add():
        # c_upd.grid_remove()     # Grid version removed.
        # c_add.grid()            
        c_upd.pack_forget()       # Hide Update Customer
        c_add.pack()              # Show Add Customer    

    root = tk.Tk()
    root.geometry('300x400')
    root.title('CAR  FLEET  MANAGEMENT  SYSTEM')

    c_add = tk.Frame(root)
    tk.Label(c_add,text="ADD NAME:").pack()
    a_ent = tk.Entry(c_add)
    a_btn = tk.Button(c_add, text='ADD', command=lambda: _add(a_ent.get()))
    a_ent.pack()
    a_btn.pack()

    c_upd = tk.Frame(root)
    tk.Label(c_upd,text="UPDATE NAME:").pack()
    u_ent = tk.Entry(c_upd)
    u_btn = tk.Button(c_upd, text='UPDATE', command=lambda: _edit(u_ent.get()))
    u_ent.pack()
    u_btn.pack()

    menus = tk.Menu()
    cst = tk.Menu(menus, tearoff=tk.FALSE)
    cst.add_command(label="Add New Customer", command=cust_add)
    cst.add_command(label="Change Customer Details", command=cust_edit)
    menus.add_cascade(label='CUSTOMERS', menu=cst)
    root.config(menu=menus)
    root.mainloop()
homepage()
```

Comment: I'm using the place instead of grid. Is there any remove() option with place..???

Comment: I assume you meant pack, not place, as you used pack in the original question. The answer is updated to use pack_forget().  This will work as long as the two options are the only things to be packed into that container.  pack_forget doesn't remember where it was originally packed.   grid_remove() does remember where is was originally gridded.  HTH

Comment: Thanks, my original issue is resolved. I also tried separating all the options in separate file to reduce load time of the modules. But, this method also seems valid.